# Why does Jasmine complain about 'Attempted to assign to readonly property' when I set selectedIndex?

Tags: javascript, jasmine, grunt-contrib-jasmine

When I run this Jasmine spec through grunt-contrib-jasmine, I get the error **TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.** pointing to the line where I set the selectedIndex attribute:

```
it('does something', function () {
    setFixtures('<select id="selectId"><option>Text</option></select>');
    var selectDOM = document.getElementById('selectId');
    selectDOM.selectedIndex = 0;
    // stripped some code here...
});
```

Does anybody know what I am missing here?
I use *phantomjs v1.9.8*, *grunt-cli v0.1.13* and *grunt-contrib-jasmine v0.9.2*.

Comment: In this example I did not make the typo, so this example will run fine. Read my answer below if you seem to have the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Got it, I made an error, but since this can be hard to find I for now will leave my question and answer here. Feel free to delete it completely though.

**I made a typo in the value I passed into the getElementById() function**, so the variable selectDOM was null. This for some reason led to the error "**TypeError: Attempted to assign to readonly property.**".

The typo was hard to see for me and the error message misleading in this case, so others might run into the same issue.